# SocketTimeoutException unhandled by RxJava

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp, rx-java2

I have an Android project developed using sdk version 25. I'm using RXJava as my thread management and Retrofit library for hit the network.

I also implemented custom Interceptor for adding     override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response? {

```
    val request = addHeader(chain)

    val response = chain.proceed(request)
    checkErrorResponse(response)

    return response
```

The api call will always inside the RX Java flow and I'm making sure of it. After I put my APK to the Playstore, a crash is detected by Crashlytics.

```
#0. Crashed: main: 0 0 0x0000000000000000
   at okio.Okio$4.newTimeoutException(Okio.java:230)
   at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:285)
   at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:241)
   at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:345)
   at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:217)
   at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:211)
   at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:75)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
   at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
   at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:120)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
   at com.payfazz.data.base.net.PayfazzInterceptor.intercept(PayfazzInterceptor.kt:24)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:92)
   at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:67)
   at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:185)
   at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:69)
   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap.subscribeActual(ObservableMap.java:33)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap.subscribeActual(ObservableMap.java:33)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDefer.subscribeActual(ObservableDefer.java:39)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDefer.subscribeActual(ObservableDefer.java:39)
   at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10842)
   at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
   at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ExecutorScheduler$ExecutorWorker$BooleanRunnable.run(ExecutorScheduler.java:260)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

As I investigated the stacktrace, I found my code here exactly at my custom interceptor. And as far as I know, the crash is caused by `SocketTimeoutException`, then a timed out request. Then I try to reproduce the timeout but it cannot be done. In my environment the exception is always catched by RX Java and sent to onError() method.

How can the crash not catched by RX Java? Should I wrap `proceed()` method  with catch block just for safety?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I am getting the same issue and it is crashing my app.

Comment: I have such kind of problem if server is not running when my client is trying to send a request to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kinds of crashes are caused when an exception is thrown outside of the RxJava lifecycle. This means your exception can be caused by either of these options:

1. Going by the [retrofit sourcecode](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava2/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava2/CallExecuteObservable.java), there might be a race condition where `Disposable.dispose()` is called but the timeout occurs before the underlying `Call` is cancelled. This would cause the timeout to be sent to the observer after it has been `disposed`, triggering the crash.
2. An error is thrown inside of the `onError` handler. This should not occur according to the RxJava protocol and will cause a crash with a `CompositeException`. Since the error you've posted does not include the exact Exception class this cannot be ruled out.

Comment: well i think the first one is the problem, if there is a crash occurred inside `onError` method, the stack should show the error caused by code inside the `onError` method. I'd definitely know it. About the first one, do you have any suggestion to prevent it?

Comment: Problems like these are quite hard to solve. Adding a try-catch for that specific exception in your `Interceptor` will probably temporarily fix your problem but might also capture exceptions that should've gone through to the observable. I recommend opening an issue on the retrofit github linking to this question so the underlying problem can be addressed.

Alternatively you could create a wrapper for RxJava's global exception handler to filter out this specific case until it is fixed. See `RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler`